# How to map a key in command-line mode but not in search mode

Tags: vim

I want to map a key in VIM in command-line mode but not in search mode(with a leading `/`), like below:

- Map Q to q
- Map W to w

Sometimes I typed the wrong command in VIM, like `:Q` and `:W`, and I want to make these wrong commands to be right.

If I can map `Q` to `q` and `W` to `w`, I can make the wrong commands to be right.

I tried `cmap Q q` and `cmap W w`, but this will also affect the search mode, i.e. `/Query` to be `/query` (actually you can't type the upper Q).

And I also tried `cabbrev Q q`, and this will also affect the search mode.

So, is there any other command that can meet my requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it, and neither is really straightforward.

With `command` you need to take care of attributes:

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=file -range=% -bang -bar W w
command! -bang -bar Q q
```

With `cabbrev` the pitfalls are described in the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev), so you need to do it like this:

```
cnoreabbrev W <C-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'w' : 'W')<CR>
```

I have a function for this purpose:

```
function! s:CAbbrev(from, to)
    execute 'cnoreabbrev ' . a:from . ' <C-r>=(getcmdtype()==#'':'' && getcmdpos()==1 ? ' . string(a:to) . ' : ' . string(a:from) . ')<CR>'
endfunction
```

With `cmap` you need the `<expr>` qualifier, and you need more or less the same precautions as with `cabbrev`:

```
cnoremap <nowait> <expr> W getcmdtype() ==# ':' && getcmdpos() == 1 ? 'w' : 'W'
```

The safest is probably the `cabbrev` way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still has some problems. I also want to  make `:Wq`, `:WQ`, `:wQ` work. So I probably need to add these three commands.

Comment: @zhiwei Yes, you'll have to do the same thing for each of them.  I'm afraid there is no shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can define a user command because it starts in upper case.

```
:command! Q q
:command! W w
```

Comment: These work fine until you want to do something like `:Q!`, or `:W file`